# Cloning values of keys in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, key, clone

I have an array (tlist) with keys linked with arrays:

```
tliste.push({"GROUP104":["321992","322052","321812","314022","0"]});
tliste.push({"GROUP108":["322011","322032","0"]});
tliste.push({"GROUP111":["322020","322021","322040","322041","313060","313072","0"]});
```

I now need to build a function to take the values of e.g. Group104 and Group111 and clone these into a new array:

```
newarrray = ["321992","322052","321812","314022","0","322020","322021","322040","322041","313060","313072","0"]
```

Preferably the new array should be ordered and the "0" should be removed - but that is of lower importance.

Comment: And what problem do you have ? What did you try ?

Comment: Array.push is a function. You should be using `tliste.push({"GROUP...`

Comment: So you are looking for how to merge arrays? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript

Comment: Basically, I'm unsure how to extract the values from the key and move them to a new array.

Comment: @FelixKling - cloning the array is one part - the other part is extracting the array from the key - have tried to google this without too much luck.

Answer (score 0):

Let the groups to be extracted be grp[].

You can do something like this -

```
// Extract groups in grp[] from origArray[]
var extractGrps = function(grps, origArray) {
    var result = [];
    for(var i =0; i<grps.length; i+=1) {
        var indxInOrigArray = indexOfObjectWithKey(origArray, grps[i]);
        if(indxInOrigArray > 0) {
            var arrLocal = origArray[indxInOrigArray].grps[i];
            for(var j=0; j<arrLocal.length;j+=1)
                result.push(arrLocal[j]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

//find Index of object in arr whose key matches the given input key
var indexOfObjectWithKey = function(arr, key) {
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i+=1) {
        if(arr[i].key) {
            return i;
        }
    }
return -1;
}
```